# How to change the size of this animated name (canvas)

Tags: javascript, html, animation

I am trying to add a animated name [like this](https://www.codecademy.com/courses/animate-your-name/0/1) on my website 
But the size of this animated name is too big. How to change the size of it, without any bug.

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/hour-of-code/js/alphabet.js"></script>
 </head>
  <body>
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/hour-of-code/js/bubbles.js"></script>
   <script>
var myName = "Codecademy";

var red = [0, 100, 63];
var orange = [40, 100, 60];
var green = [75, 100, 40];
var blue = [196, 77, 55];
var purple = [280, 50, 60];
var letterColors = [red, orange, green, blue, purple];

drawName(myName, letterColors);

if(10 < 3)
{
bubbleShape = 'square';
}
else
{
bubbleShape = 'circle';
}

 bounceBubbles();
 </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The bubbles that form each letter are decided by arrays of data within the alphabet.js script. This means that regular font mechanics like size do not apply.

You can modify the size of the characters by scaling the coordinates of the bubbles after they are converted from hex to bubble array.

Here's a simple way to apply the scaling. The change is made to the contents of the bubbles.js script:

```
function Point(x, y, z, size, color) {      
var globalSizer = 0.3;
 x = Math.round(x * globalSizer);
 y = Math.round(y * globalSizer);
 z = Math.round(z * globalSizer);
size = Math.round(size * globalSizer);
```

Decreasing the value of globalSizer will cause the letters to shrink. Here's the whole thing working:

```js
var myName = "TinyTinyText";

var red = [0, 100, 63];
var orange = [40, 100, 60];
var green = [75, 100, 40];
var blue = [196, 77, 55];
var purple = [280, 50, 60];
var letterColors = [red, orange, green, blue, purple];

var canvas = $("#myCanvas");
var canvasHeight;
var canvasWidth;
var ctx;
var pointCollection;
 
document.rotationForce = 0.0;
document.Friction = 0.85;

var white = [0, 0, 100];
var black = [0, 0, 27];
var red = [0, 100, 63];
var orange = [40, 100, 60];
var green = [75, 100, 40];
var blue = [196, 77, 55];
var purple = [280, 50, 60];

drawName(myName, letterColors);

if(10 < 3)
{
bubbleShape = 'square';
}
else
{
bubbleShape = 'circle';
}

 bounceBubbles();
 
 /*

     --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     
     Bubble.js...
     
     --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

 */

 function Vector(x, y, z) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.z = z;
 
    this.set = function (x, y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    };
}
 
function PointCollection() {
    this.mousePos = new Vector(0, 0);
    this.pointCollectionX = 0;
    this.pointCollectionY = 0;
    this.points = [];
 
    this.update = function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.points.length; i++) {
            var point = this.points[i];
 
            var dx = this.mousePos.x - point.curPos.x;
            var dy = this.mousePos.y - point.curPos.y;
            var dd = (dx * dx) + (dy * dy);
            var d = Math.sqrt(dd);
 
            point.targetPos.x = d < 150 ? point.curPos.x - dx : point.originalPos.x;
            point.targetPos.y = d < 150 ? point.curPos.y - dy : point.originalPos.y;
 
            point.update();
        }
    };
 
    this.shake = function () {
        var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) - 2;
 
        for (var i = 0; i < this.points.length; i++) {
            var point = this.points[i];
            var dx = this.mousePos.x - point.curPos.x;
            var dy = this.mousePos.y - point.curPos.y;
            var dd = (dx * dx) + (dy * dy);
            var d = Math.sqrt(dd);
            if (d < 50) {
                this.pointCollectionX = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) - 2;
                this.pointCollectionY = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) - 2;
            }
            point.draw(bubbleShape, this.pointCollectionX, this.pointCollectionY);
        }
    };
 
    this.draw = function (bubbleShape, reset) {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.points.length; i++) {
            var point = this.points[i];
 
            if (point === null)
                continue;
 
            if (window.reset) {
                this.pointCollectionX = 0;
                this.pointCollectionY = 0;
                this.mousePos = new Vector(0, 0);
            }
 
            point.draw(bubbleShape, this.pointCollectionX, this.pointCollectionY, reset);
        }
    };
 
    this.reset = function (bubbleShape) {};
}


 
function Point(x, y, z, size, color) {  
    var globalSizer = 0.3;
     x = Math.round(x * globalSizer);
     y = Math.round(y * globalSizer);
     z = Math.round(z * globalSizer);
    size = Math.round(size * globalSizer);
    
    this.curPos = new Vector(x, y, z);
    this.color = color;
 
    this.friction = document.Friction;
    this.rotationForce = document.rotationForce;
    this.springStrength = 0.1;
 
    this.originalPos = new Vector(x, y, z);
    this.radius = size;
    this.size = size;
    this.targetPos = new Vector(x, y, z);
    this.velocity = new Vector(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
 
    this.update = function () {
        var dx = this.targetPos.x - this.curPos.x;
        var dy = this.targetPos.y - this.curPos.y;
        // Orthogonal vector is [-dy,dx]
        var ax = dx * this.springStrength - this.rotationForce * dy;
        var ay = dy * this.springStrength + this.rotationForce * dx;
 
        this.velocity.x += ax;
        this.velocity.x *= this.friction;
        this.curPos.x += this.velocity.x;
 
        this.velocity.y += ay;
        this.velocity.y *= this.friction;
        this.curPos.y += this.velocity.y;
 
        var dox = this.originalPos.x - this.curPos.x;
        var doy = this.originalPos.y - this.curPos.y;
        var dd = (dox * dox) + (doy * doy);
        var d = Math.sqrt(dd);
 
        this.targetPos.z = d / 100 + 1;
        var dz = this.targetPos.z - this.curPos.z;
        var az = dz * this.springStrength;
        this.velocity.z += az;
        this.velocity.z *= this.friction;
        this.curPos.z += this.velocity.z;
 
        this.radius = this.size * this.curPos.z;
        if (this.radius < 1) this.radius = 1;
    };
 
    this.draw = function (bubbleShape, dx, dy) {
        ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
        if (bubbleShape == "square") {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.fillRect(this.curPos.x + dx, this.curPos.y + dy, this.radius * 1.5, this.radius * 1.5);
        } else {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(this.curPos.x + dx, this.curPos.y + dy, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
            ctx.fill();
        }
    };
}
 
function makeColor(hslList, fade) {
    var hue = hslList[0] /*- 17.0 * fade / 1000.0*/ ;
    var sat = hslList[1] /*+ 81.0 * fade / 1000.0*/ ;
    var lgt = hslList[2] /*+ 58.0 * fade / 1000.0*/ ;
    return "hsl(" + hue + "," + sat + "%," + lgt + "%)";
}
 
function phraseToHex(phrase) {
    var hexphrase = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < phrase.length; i++) {
        hexphrase += phrase.charCodeAt(i).toString(16);
    }
    return hexphrase;
}
 
function initEventListeners() {
    $(window).bind('resize', updateCanvasDimensions).bind('mousemove', onMove);
 
    canvas.ontouchmove = function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        onTouchMove(e);
    };
 
    canvas.ontouchstart = function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    };
}
 
function updateCanvasDimensions() {
    canvas.attr({
        height: 500,
        width: 1000
    });
    canvasWidth = canvas.width();
    canvasHeight = canvas.height();
    draw();
}
 
function onMove(e) {
    if (pointCollection) {
        pointCollection.mousePos.set(e.pageX - canvas.offset().left, e.pageY - canvas.offset().top);
    }
}
 
function onTouchMove(e) {
    if (pointCollection) {
        pointCollection.mousePos.set(e.targetTouches[0].pageX - canvas.offset().left, e.targetTouches[0].pageY - canvas.offset().top);
    }
}
 
function bounceName() {
    shake();
    setTimeout(bounceName, 30);
}
 
function bounceBubbles() {
    draw();
    update();
    setTimeout(bounceBubbles, 30);
}
 
function draw(reset) {
    var tmpCanvas = canvas.get(0);
 
    if (tmpCanvas.getContext === null) {
        return;
    }
 
    ctx = tmpCanvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
 
    bubbleShape = typeof bubbleShape !== 'undefined' ? bubbleShape : "circle";
 
    if (pointCollection) {
        pointCollection.draw(bubbleShape, reset);
    }
}
 
function shake() {
    var tmpCanvas = canvas.get(0);
 
    if (tmpCanvas.getContext === null) {
        return;
    }
 
    ctx = tmpCanvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
 
    bubbleShape = typeof bubbleShape !== 'undefined' ? bubbleShape : "circle";
 
    if (pointCollection) {
        pointCollection.shake(bubbleShape);
    }
}
 
function update() {
    if (pointCollection)
        pointCollection.update();
}
 
function drawName(name, letterColors) {
    updateCanvasDimensions();
    var g = [];
    var offset = 0;
 
    function addLetter(cc_hex, ix, letterCols) {
        if (typeof letterCols !== 'undefined') {
            if (Object.prototype.toString.call(letterCols) === '[object Array]' && Object.prototype.toString.call(letterCols[0]) === '[object Array]') {
                letterColors = letterCols;
            }
            if (Object.prototype.toString.call(letterCols) === '[object Array]' && typeof letterCols[0] === "number") {
                letterColors = [letterCols];
            }
        } else {
            // if undefined set black
            letterColors = [[0, 0, 27]];
        }
 
        if (document.alphabet.hasOwnProperty(cc_hex)) {
            var chr_data = document.alphabet[cc_hex].P;
            var bc = letterColors[ix % letterColors.length];
 
            for (var i = 0; i < chr_data.length; ++i) {
                point = chr_data[i];
 
                g.push(new Point(point[0] + offset,
                    point[1],
                    0.0,
                    point[2],
                    makeColor(bc, point[3])));
            }
            offset += document.alphabet[cc_hex].W;
        }
    }
 
    var hexphrase = phraseToHex(name);
 
    var col_ix = -1;
    for (var i = 0; i < hexphrase.length; i += 2) {
        var cc_hex = "A" + hexphrase.charAt(i) + hexphrase.charAt(i + 1);
        if (cc_hex != "A20") {
            col_ix++;
        }
        addLetter(cc_hex, col_ix, letterColors);
    }
 
    for (var j = 0; j < g.length; j++) {
        g[j].curPos.x = (canvasWidth / 2 - offset / 2) + g[j].curPos.x;
        g[j].curPos.y = (canvasHeight / 2 - 105) + g[j].curPos.y;
        g[j].originalPos.x = (canvasWidth / 2 - offset / 2) + g[j].originalPos.x;
        g[j].originalPos.y = (canvasHeight / 2 - 105) + g[j].originalPos.y;
    }
 
    pointCollection = new PointCollection();
    pointCollection.points = g;
    initEventListeners();
}
 
window.reset = false;
 
$(window).mouseleave(function () {
    window.reset = true;
});
 
$(window).mouseenter(function () {
    window.reset = false;
});
 

 
setTimeout(updateCanvasDimensions, 30);
```

```html
<script src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/hour-of-code/js/alphabet.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Awesome, but i am not understanding anything from that long code. Can you just tell me, where i can edit the size? Thanks

Comment: I did, look at the first block of code in my answer. The bubble.js file does not expose an API that allows you to change the size of the letters. Instead, you have to download the long bubbles.js file, locate the line that reads "function Point(x, y, z, size, color) {", then insert the code that looks like this: var globalSizer = 0.3;
 x = Math.round(x * globalSizer);
 y = Math.round(y * globalSizer);
 z = Math.round(z * globalSizer);
size = Math.round(size * globalSizer);                   And then, save the modified bubbles.js file on your server and point your web page to it.